# java.lang.IllegalStateException when call requestdispathcher.forward(request.respone);

Tags: java, servlets

```
try {

    PaperDAOImpl objPaperDAOImpl = new PaperDAOImpl();
    AuthorDAOImpl objAuthorDAOImpl = new AuthorDAOImpl();
    List<papersBean> listPaperBean = new ArrayList<papersBean>();
    List<List<Author>> listOfListAuthor = new ArrayList<List<Author>>();

    String title = null;
    String author = null;

    if (request.getParameter("searchtitle") != null) {
        title = request.getParameter("title").trim();
        if (title.trim().equals("")) {
            String error = " You must choice option search";
            request.setAttribute("error", error);

        } else {
            listPaperBean = objPaperDAOImpl.SearchPaperByTitle(title
                    .trim());
            request.setAttribute("listresult", listPaperBean);
            // Get List Author Name , List

            if (!listPaperBean.isEmpty()) {

                for (int i = 0; i < listPaperBean.size(); i++) {
                    List<Author> listAuthor = objAuthorDAOImpl
                            .GetListAuthorByIdPaper(listPaperBean
                                    .get(i).getIdPaper());
                    if (listAuthor != null) {
                        listOfListAuthor.add(listAuthor);
                    }
                }
                int size = 0; // for debug
                size = listOfListAuthor.size(); // for debug

                request.setAttribute("lolAuthor", listOfListAuthor);
                RequestDispatcher rd = request
                        .getRequestDispatcher("front-end/search.jsp");
                rd.forward(request, response);
                return;

            }
        }
    }

} catch (ServletException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

finally {

}
```

---

This is MyServlet for Search data.

When i debug to util row :

```
 `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("front-end/search.jsp");`
```

Everything ok. And  `"listOfListAuthor" , "listPaperBean"` have data... But when debug to row :

`rd.forward();` ---> I have a problem i still can't fix.

```
**Aug 19, 2012 3:48:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
at managerpapers.system.servletController.FESearchTitle.processRequest(FESearchTitle.java:73)--This is rows : `rd.forward()`;**
```

This is MyServlet for Search data ! I debug all day for this . This is my thesis . A don't understand about servlet master . Does anyone have anyidea ?

This is MyServlet for Search data ! I debug all day for this . This is my thesis . A don't understand about servlet master . Does anyone have anyidea ?

Answer (score 0):

As said in [Javadoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/servlet/index.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) servletContext's requestDispatcher must begin with a "/" and is interpreted as relative to the current context root.
so instead of:
 `RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("front-end/search.jsp");`

try this :
`RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/front-end/search.jsp");`

I hope it'll help you

Comment: @lebronjamesuit I'm so happy that it's working now :D. I think 2 years is enough for adding a "/" to your code :)